# AWS CLI commands is not picking the ASG name from Varaible

Tags: powershell, aws-cli

Hi I am running below AWS CLI command in powershell but I am not able to pass the ASG name from a variable:

```
    $asgname = agaonline-system-ASG
    aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --query 'AutoScalingGroups[?contains(Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value, `$asgname`)].[AutoScalingGroupName]' --region eu-west-1 --output text | Out-File C:\temp\asg_name.txt
```

Basically the I am not able to pass the value $asgname to AWS CLI commands.

When I am running below commands it's giving me perfect output:

```
    aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --query 'AutoScalingGroups[?contains(Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value, `agaonline-system-ASG`)].[AutoScalingGroupName]' --region eu-west-1 --output text | Out-File C:\temp\asg_name.txt
```

Can anyone help me with that.

Comment: Not sure about the backticks in the query string, but because you use single quotes around it, `$asgname` will not be expanded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes do not expand variables. Use double quotes to do that.
Also, I think you should not use bakticks in the query string.

Try

```
"AutoScalingGroups[?contains(Tags[?Key=='Name'].Value, '$asgname')].[AutoScalingGroupName]"
```